# jira jenkins stormrunner integration

Tags: jenkins, jira, stormrunner-load

I have set up StormRunner to run tests when Jenkins builds which results in an XML file being generated in the workspace. I need to report any failure on JIRA and generate a ticket. Any tips on how to go about this

Comment: Is this question regarding SRF (stormrunner-functional) or SRL (stormrunner-load)?

Comment: @Motti StromRunner Load - Thanks

Comment: Re-tagged the question